# How to import comma separated JSON documents into Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have dozens of JSON files given by my colleague, they are comma separated documents, look like as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566a8d08b9ac7b7dc2ddb90a"),
    "login_ip" : "180.173.143.x",
    "login_time" : NumberLong("1478757697373"),
    "logout_time" : NumberLong("1478757878035"),
    "role" : NumberInt("5"),
    "server_ip" : "115.28.94.x",
    "thirdPartyId" : NumberInt("-1"),
    "ver" : NumberInt("1036")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566a8d0db9ac7b7dc2ddb90b"),
    "login_ip" : "116.226.162.x",
    "login_time" : NumberLong("1456103011531"),
    "logout_time" : NumberLong("1456111567354"),
    "role" : NumberInt("10002"),
    "server_ip" : "115.28.94.x",
    "thirdPartyId" : NumberInt("6"),
    "ver" : NumberInt("1056")
},
...
```

I've tried to import them to my local mongodb with `mongoimport` tool, but it has trouble to locate the starting position of the second document, complains about the syntax of these files, in spite of the fact that the first document is parsed into the db.

```
+ mongoimport.exe --db eques --collection users_2017_04_25 --type json --bypassDocumentValidation --file 'E:\sample\mongdo/users_2017_04_25.json'
2017-06-12T14:01:32.029+0800    connected to: localhost
2017-06-12T14:01:32.040+0800    Failed: error processing document #2: invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value
2017-06-12T14:01:32.040+0800    imported 0 documents
```

PS: there're many files to be imported, please don't suggest me turn them into JSON arrays.

Please help.

Comment: Umm they are already JSON documents.

Comment: @NeilLunn so? please advise me!

Comment: Do they look "exactly" like you show above? If so then this is not valid JSON. It kind of looks like someone piped the output from the mongodb shell, which of course was the wrong thing to do here. Hence this would take some pre-processing to actually make them work. Given the likely source, is there any way to get the export re-written? That would be the easiest course.

Comment: @NeilLunn above is a snippet of the files to be imported, and you're right, my colleague actully exported these files from MongoBooster, I'll let him help me get it right, thanks.

Comment: Since the source is coming from MongoDB in the first place. Maybe you should be using [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) or [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) in the first place. Probably the latter considering the data is just going from MongoDB to MongoDB. That's my advice.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you very much, it's because incompatible format(Mongoshell vs. Mongoimport), the document above is in the former format, but `mongoimport` only recognize the latter, I can't solve it so quickly without your guidance, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The JSON documents above is expressed in [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson) much of it `mongoimport` tool doesn't understand.

You should export your data in standard JSON format first(in Mongo world, it's call [Strict mode](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)), then feed it to `mongoimport` tool.